# parsing a conditional from a string

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, eval

I have two numpy arrays a, b and a string of the form `s = "1.5 * b if 2*a > 7 else a + b"`

I would like to create an array c, which will evaluate the string on the arrays in an efficient manner.

Example of a desired behavior:

```
a = np.array([1, 4])
b = np.array([3, 1])
s = "1.5 * b if 2*a > 7 else a + b"
print(my_eval(a, b, s))

[4, 1.5]
```

Was thinking of something like
`f = np.vectorize(eval(s)); map(a, b, f)`

What's the best way to do it? The number of arrays in the expression can be larger (but bounded by something reasonable.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the solution will differ much either way

Comment: `python2.x` isn't supported by `numpy` versions for 3+ years. There are not many users that can test with `python2`. `np.fromiter((eval(s) for a, b in zip(a1, b1)), dtype=float)` works with renamed arrays (`python3`). The code in the string does not work with `np.arrays`. I don't think there is a simple way without parsing the string.

Comment: I've added the parenthesis around print, since you guys feel so strongly about it :)

Comment: Please define "best way". Does it means fast? simple? robust? pythonic? Besides this, please define the kind of expression that can be accepted or not (ie. the language of the expression). For example: can functions be used in the expression? can other operators like division/subtraction be used? are sub-expression allowed. Etc.

Comment: I've added the `numpy2.7` tag. Please remove when no longer needed. I'm only trying to make the question more likely to get answers. This is an interesting question.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, thanks - doing eval on the individual entries work. Do I understand you correctly, that parsing the string is mainly necessary b/c eval can't handle ternary operators for numpy arrays? Otherwise, eval("1.5*b*(2*a>7)+(a+b)*(2*a<=7))" works and is probably faster

Comment: The problem is that conditions are ambiguous with arrays, there is not one boolean result but an array of booleans (you can read more about it in one of the [4300 posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+truth+value+of+an+array+with+more+than+one+element+is+ambiguous.+Use+a.any()+or+a.all()+site:stackoverflow.com) on stackoverflow (4.3% of all `numpy` questions? Interesting)).

Comment: Please fix "stRing" spelling in question title, it will improve "searchability"

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the efficiency, but you could use the given string expression `s` in a function definition template string, execute it into a local dictionary with `exec`, vectorize it for non-[ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) expressions, and then call it within the proposed `my_eval` function:

```
import numpy as np


def my_eval(s, a, b):

    locals_dict = {}

    # Generates source code to define a new function from the given string.
    source = f"def f(a, b): return {s}"

    # Executes the function definition script into locals_dict.
    exec(source, globals(), locals_dict)

    # Defines a vectorized version of the newly defined function.
    f = np.vectorize(locals_dict["f"])

    # Applies the function.
    return f(a, b)


s = "1.5 * b if 2 * a > 7 else a + b"
a = np.array([1, 4]).astype(float)
b = np.array([3, 1]).astype(float)
c = my_eval(s, a, b)

print(c)
```

This can modified to handle variable numbers of input arguments. For example, something like the following could handle up to 26 different input arrays, one for each letter of the alphabet:

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase


def my_eval(s, *args):

    locals_dict = {}

    # Generates source code to define a new function from the given string.
    params = ", ".join(list(ascii_lowercase[0:len(args)]))
    source = f"def f(*args): {params} = args; return {s}"

    # Executes the function definition script into locals_dict.
    exec(source, globals(), locals_dict)

    # Defines a vectorized version of the newly defined function.
    f = np.vectorize(locals_dict["f"])

    # Applies the function.
    return f(*args)
```